# Why are my boxes not the same height when specifying height as a function of width and content?

Tags: boxes

- I save a box containing a `\parbox`.
- I set height of other `\parbox`es to the height of my saved box using TeX `\the\ht\box`

## Code

For some reason, not all boxes are of the same size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}% perfectly size box around content
\setlength\fboxrule{.1pt}

\begin{document}

% Our goal is to specify the height dynamically as a function of the width and content of the box, which we set explicitly here:
\newsavebox{\tmpparbox}
\savebox{\tmpparbox}{\fbox{\parbox{40mm}{This parbox is top aligned with top-aligned content. And more text to fill it up.}}}

% I can use TeX or LaTeX to get the height of the saved box.
%\the\ht\tmpparbox % TeX

%\newlength{\tmpparboxht} % LaTeX
%\settoheight{\tmpparboxht}{\usebox{\tmpparbox}}

Here is the \string\savebox: \usebox{\tmpparbox}
\bigbreak

Target height: \the\ht\tmpparbox

\kern20pt\hrule\kern20pt

This is not a parbox. \fbox{\parbox[t][\the\ht\tmpparbox][t]{40mm}{This parbox is top aligned with top-aligned content. And more text to fill it up.}}
\bigbreak
This is not a parbox. \fbox{\parbox[b][\the\ht\tmpparbox][t]{40mm}{This parbox is bottom aligned with top-aligned content. And more text to fill it up.}}
\bigbreak
This is not a parbox. \fbox{\parbox[t][\the\ht\tmpparbox][c]{40mm}{This parbox is top aligned with center-aligned content. And more text to fill it up.}}
\bigbreak
This is not a parbox. \fbox{\parbox[t][\the\ht\tmpparbox][b]{40mm}{This parbox is top aligned with bottom-aligned content. And more text to fill it up.}}
\bigbreak
This is not a parbox. \fbox{\parbox[c][\the\ht\tmpparbox][t]{40mm}{This parbox is center aligned with top-aligned content. And more text to fill it up.}}
\bigbreak

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your first box says it is top aligned but it is vertically centred and you are just taking the height not the depth, so around half its vertical extent.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, so I need both height and depth.

Comment: yes and then probably subtract boxmaxdepth, the inner height argument to parbox doesn't directly relate to either the height or height+depth of the resulting box, just as `\textheight` doesn't relate to the height+depth of a page as by design the depth is ignored so you get even bottom baselines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error is that , as your image shows, the box you save is vertically centred not top aligned so by using `\ht` you are getting around half the required value. You could use `\ht` plus `\dp` but that would in fact be too much as what you need to specify for the height argument to `\parbox` is the target height of the text, not including the depth of the final row beyond the final baseline.

So best would be to use a `\parbox[b]` to save the box (and don't use `\fbox` as that would hide the last real row of text)  and then use `\ht` of the saved box.

Comment: Could you please explain the first part about `\ht` and my box being vertically centered and not top aligned? Why is `\ht` about half? Just want to make sure I know what is being measured here...

Comment: Side note, if I use a new dimen register,  `\boxsize=\dimexpr\the\ht\templatexbox+\dp\templatexbox\relax`, and feed that into my `\parbox[b]{\boxsize}{...}`, the `\fbox` surrounds the dips in letters like "p". (I took `\fbox` out of the `\savebox`)